# Displaying Html in Android Listview

Tags: android, html, listview, twitter

I have a twitter feed in my app and i am trying to change the appearance of hashtags, mentions, links etc by wrapping them in html.

heres what it looks like so far :

[image]

My question is, how do i get my list view to recognise the Html tags??

Here is my list view code:

```
try{
        Twitter twits = jsonToTwitter(result);

        // lets write the results to the console as well
        for (Tweet tweet : twits) {

            // send the tweets to the adapter for rendering
                            listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);   

            textview  = (TextView)  getView().findViewById(R.id.text);
            ArrayAdapter<Tweet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item, twits);

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);


            mProgressDialog.hide();
        }

        }catch(NullPointerException e){

            mProgressDialog.hide();
            System.out.println("No Network Available");

        }
    }
```

Wrapping the hashtags etc in html:

```
@Override
public String  toString(){


    Pattern mentionPattern = Pattern.compile("(@[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
    Pattern hashtagPattern = Pattern.compile("(#[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
    Pattern urlPattern = Patterns.WEB_URL;

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(Text.length());
    Matcher o = hashtagPattern.matcher(Text);

    while (o.find()) {
        o.appendReplacement(sb, "<b>" + o.group(1) + "</b>");
    }
    o.appendTail(sb);

    Matcher n = mentionPattern.matcher(sb.toString());
    sb = new StringBuffer(sb.length());

    while (n.find()) {
        n.appendReplacement(sb, "<font color=\"#657383\">" + n.group(1) + "</font>");
    }
    n.appendTail(sb);

    Matcher m = urlPattern.matcher(sb.toString());
    sb = new StringBuffer(sb.length());

    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, "<font color=\"#EDDA74\">" + m.group(1) + "</font>");
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);




    return  sb + "\n"+ getDateCreated() ;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Adapter's getView() method (where you actually populate your Views), you can set the text of your TextView as HTML:

```
mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(yourHtmlString));
```

The important part is:

```
Html.fromHtml(String)
```

Also noticed something else:

```
for (Tweet tweet : twits) {
        // send the tweets to the adapter for rendering
        listview = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listview);   
        textview  = (TextView)  getView().findViewById(R.id.text);
        ArrayAdapter<Tweet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Tweet>(getActivity(), R.layout.listview_item, twits);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mProgressDialog.hide();
    }
```

Why are you creating a new adapter every single time you loop through your tweets? You should be creating it once and adding the data to it if you need to (which you don't since you're supplying the adapter with your data).

Comment: Yes, it is. I've used it multiple times in that exact context we're referring to. Your issue is actually with your implementation of the ArrayAdapter (which you can't just use). You're going to have to create a custom Adapter that implements ArrayAdapter, override the getView() method (as I mentioned in my answer), and then inside there make the call to Html.fromHtml() when setting the text. If you don't do that, the ArrayAdapter will never know to set the text as an Html String and not a regular one.